# Magento - 2.2.4 Community Edition : How to create two separate admins for separate websites in one admin panel?

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4

How to create two separate admins for separate websites in one admin panel?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Mg1.png]

I created websites for Vizag and for Hyderabad as domain.com/vizag and domain.com/hyd.

We want to create two admins for Vizag and Hyderabad.

Vizag website and Hyderabad website are two different websites under single magento installation.

Means, worked on multiple websites. Vizag store wants to see only vizag website and hyderabad store wants to see hyderabad website only. but main admin can see both website's actions.

Comment: You mean 2 admin users?

Comment: community or enterprise edition?

Comment: I think @PhilippSander answer is the one you are looking for. You basically want Advanced Permission Extension.

Comment: I suggest you to look for few extensions that will do your work. Because promoting an extension or extension company is against the rules of stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in the community edition right now. The feature to restrict access to websites and stores for certain role is exclusive for the enterprise edition.

[you will need a buy module to get this functionality in CE](https://amasty.com/advanced-permissions-for-magento-2.html)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara thanks! i got the link wrong. i corrected it

Comment: @nukalasatish you have to check yourself if there's another extension. I only know this one. I sue it in one of my projects and I'm very happy with it

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunatly its not possible to create something like  a "permission Admin system" within the Community Edtiotion - If you want to use this straight from magento you have to upgrate to EE.

Since i have faced this issue on my own project i did some research and found the following extensions:

https://amasty.com/advanced-permissions-for-magento-2.html

Maybe its worth a look and check the functionality.